# How should I handle 'match may not be exhaustive' warning in Scala?

Tags: scala

Upon upgrading my code to Scala 2.13 from 2.12 I get a bunch of these kinds of warnings:

```
[warn] /mystuff/ScalaJack/core/src/main/scala/co.blocke.scalajack/model/TypeAdapterCache.scala:100:40: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Nil
[warn]                     val head :: tail = factories
```

(factories is a list of some type T)

This isn't a match statement, it's an assignment.  I agree with the compiler that this would fail if factories was Nil, but what's the better way to do this assignment?

Comment: While this is creating a new two new values, this is a form of pattern matching. And the compile is correct, it may fail. If you are sure that the list may never be empty either consider disabling the warning using [**silencer**](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) or a [`NonEmptyList`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/NonEmptyList.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your operation fails if the input is `Nil`. If you know the list can not be empty, you can use the `NonEmptyList` type from cats: https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/NonEmptyList.html. Otherwise, you can use a pattern match to more clearly express your intent in that case, something like:

```scala
val (head, tail) = factories match {
  case h :: t => (h,t)
  case Nil => ??? //Process empty list however you like
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val head :: tail = factories
```

Although this is not a `match` expression, it does involve pattern matching `factories` against the pattern `head::tail` which can fail if `factories` is `Nil`.

The solution is to split the list safely and then handle the possible errors:

```
val (head, tail) = factories.splitAt(1)
```

`head` will be a `List` and therefore potentially empty, so test with `isEmpty` or convert to an `Option` using `headOption` and then use the standard `Option` methods to process it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Ethan's explanation, the code could be refactored as below

```
factories match {
  case head::tail => // your original code
  case Nil => // handle it or leave as _ 
}
```

Comment: _"Or..."_ is not a very good explanation, we always add explanations in answers.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it